# Show that a subalgebra is commutative.

Tags: commutative-algebra, banach-algebras, noncommutative-algebra

If $B$ is an unital algebra (even not commutative), how do I show that the subalgebra spanned by the elements $1$, $f$ and $(f - \lambda1)^{-1}$ is commutative?
Thank you.

Comment: Right! I was stupidly trying to show that $(\lambda_{1}1 + \lambda_{2}f + \lambda_{3}(f-\lambda1)^{-1})(\mu_{1}1 + \mu_{2}f + \mu_{3}(f-\lambda1)^{-1}) = (\mu_{1}1 + \mu_{2}f + \mu_{3}(f-\lambda1)^{-1})(\lambda_{1}1 + \lambda_{2}f + \lambda_{3}(f-\lambda1)^{-1})$ XD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It suffices to show that the generators commute and for that you just need to show that $f$ and $(f - \lambda1)^{-1}$ commute with each other ($1$ commutes with everything).  Well, note that $f$ and $f - \lambda1$ commute and if $x$, and $y$ commute then $x$ and $y^{-1}$ commute:
$$xy^{-1} = y^{-1}yxy^{-1} = y^{-1}xyy^{-1} = y^{-1}x$$